# Understanding Javascript Chaining Patterns

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I ran this code into the console and tried calling:

```
obj.foo().bar().coo().moo();
```

This was my previous code:

```
    function bar() {
  this.coo = function () {
    this.moo = function () {
      console.log("yay");
    }
  }
}

obj = {
  foo : function () {this.bar = bar}
};
```

The error that returned was "TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined". Although, when I wrote:

```
obj.foo();
obj.bar();
obj.coo();
obj.moo();
```

It worked fine. Why didn't the first call using method chaining not work as if I was separately calling each method.

Comment: you want to un-nest those methods...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't return anything. You need to add `return this` at the end of each of your functions in order to have an object to chain.

Comment: If this solved your problem, don't forget to hit the check mark to let others know that it was solved.